# Change the foreignKey id to another Field

Tags: python, django, django-models

I don't know if there is a logic for this, because i seen it before when I programed with C# and VB, but in Django, it's seems hard to get it.

So what I want to ?
I want the table in database save the name and not the id of the foreignKey.
And this is the model.py

```
from pyexpat import model
from statistics import mode
from venv import create
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.base import Model
from django.forms import IntegerField



class Post(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)


class Person(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"({self.name} is {self.post})"



class Room(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length= 150, unique = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)


class Classification(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(auto_created=False)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_created=True)

    def __str__(self):
       return f"({self.name} Take {self.room}  at {self.date})"
```

The result in Database table:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvMlp.png)

What I want to see in the database table, is that Django replace the id's in name_id column with names, and room_id with room names

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [**`to_field=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.to_field) to specify to what the `ForeignKey` should point. This should *always* be a *unique* field in the targetting model. So you can use:

```
class Classification(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, to_field='name', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField()
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
       return f'({self.person_id} Take {self.room}  at {self.date})'
```

You should likely however recreate the migrations for the `Classification` model, and thus let this create a `ForeignKey` that references the `name` of the `Person` model.

You can here use `self.person_id` to avoid making an extra query to load the `Person` object. This will thus improve the efficiency when calling the `__str__` method of a `Classification` object.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make the name a Pk in the Model `primary_key=True`
then in the ForeignKey set the `to_field='name'`

very easy ...